# complex equations/ eulers formula / sin*cos

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I am going to solve the equation: $$\sin(z)\cdot \cos(z) = i$$ in my mathematics class. I can get pretty far by using eulers formula to manipulate the expression, and end up where i have
$$e^{2iz} = -2 \pm \sqrt5$$ but from here i dont get it anymore.

The solution I have been provided does somehow make the root/r equal 3 - and end up with an expression like this for when you plus the root of five part:

$$3 \cdot e^{\arctan \dfrac{\sqrt5}{-2} + 2 \pi n} $$
But both root of five and $2$ is a part of the real part (not the imaginary) so i dont understand how one can use it like this both to get the 3 (r) in front and also in the arctg part to get the angle.

Thanks for help!

Comment: With $\sin\left( x \right) \cdot \cos\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin\left( 2 \cdot x \right)$ aka $\frac{1}{2} \cdot \sin\left( 2 \cdot z \right) = i$ the equation should be easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The equation being
$$\sin(2z)=2i$$ let $z=a+I b$ and expand to have two equations corresponding to the real and imaginary parts.
$$\sin (2 a) \cosh (2 b)=0\tag 1$$
$$\cos (2 a) \sinh (2 b)=2\tag 2$$

Since $\cosh(2b)$ is always larger than $1$, the solution for $a$ correspond to
$$\sin(2a)=0 \qquad \implies a= k \frac \pi 2$$

Knowing $a$, the second equation write
$$\sinh(2b)=\pm 2$$  Using the expoential representation
$$\frac{e^{2b}-e^{-2b}}2=\pm 2 $$ which are quadratic polynomials in $e^{2b}$. So the roots
$$b_{\pm}=\pm\frac{1}{2} \log \left(2+\sqrt{5}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

> The given solution is incorrect. Observe that the solution is real, and hence its impossible for the original equation to hold true. As a matter of fact, where your work ended up; $e^{2iz} = -2 \pm \sqrt{5}$, points in the correct direction.

Shall we continue:

$$
\text{Let} \, z = x + iy
\\\Rightarrow -2 \pm \sqrt{5} = e^{2i(x + iy)} = e^{-2y} \cdot e^{2ix}
\\\Im{(e^{2ix})} = 0 \implies \sin{2x} = 0 
\\\iff x = \frac{n\pi}{2}, \, n \in \mathbb{Z}
\\\quad
\\\text{But, $\cos{(k\pi)} = \pm 1, \, k \in \mathbb{Z}$} 
\\\therefore \begin{cases}{e^{-2y} = -2 + \sqrt{5}, \quad x = n\pi}
\\-e^{-2y} = - 2 - \sqrt{5}, \quad x = \dfrac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2}
\end{cases}, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}
\\\quad
\\\text{whence} \, \begin{cases}{y = - \dfrac{1}{2}\ln{(\sqrt{5} - 2)} =  \dfrac{1}{2}\ln{(\sqrt{5} + 2)}
\\ y = - \dfrac{1}{2}\ln{(\sqrt{5} + 2)}}
\end{cases}
\\\quad
$$

$$\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid black]{
\\\therefore 
z = \begin{cases}{n\pi + \dfrac{1}{2}i\cdot\ln{(\sqrt{5} + 2)} \\\dfrac{(2n + 1)\pi}{2} - \dfrac{1}{2}i\cdot\ln{(\sqrt{5} + 2)}}
\end{cases}, \quad n \in \mathbb{Z}}
$$